# How to resize page border HTML/CCS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have recently been getting into HTML and CSS and practicing by making my own CV.

Currently, I have an issue with making the page border in line with the contents in the body. I have resized the body and all the contents inside to fit within 1210px, but I can't manage to get the page to be that size. I suspect this cannot be done as the page will always look like that unless I use my margins and just center everything. Sorry for the bad problem description, its easier to see if you just look at the screen shot! I have made all my borders appear in red using the '*' in CSS. As you can see, the page extends beyond the borders!

[image]

My CSS code is as follows:

```
*
{
    border: red dashed 1px;
}


html {
    width: 1210px;
}

h3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

h4 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

h5 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}
li {
    width: 800px;
}
 #phoneNumber {
 position: relative;
        left: 950px;
        top: -110px;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-decoration:blink;
        color: black;
        width: 200px;
 }

 #emailaddress {
        position: relative;
        left: 630px;
        top: -150px;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-decoration:blink;
        color: black;
 }


#phoneIcon 
{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 617px;
    top: -60px;
}

#emailIcon
{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 670px;
    top: -130px;

}

body{
    background-color: #C4D2E0;
    width: 1210px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    margin: 5px;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 1200px;
}
span {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#header {

border-width: thin;
border-color:  blue;
border-style: solid;

background-color:#6B8FB2;
position: relative;
height: 250px;
text-align: center;
font-family: monospace;
font-style: oblique;
text-align: justify;
width: 1200px;

}

 #aboutmeDiv
 {
     position: relative;
     max-width: 1100px;
     left: 210px;
     top: -250px;
     margin-right: 800px;
     border-style: dashed green 1px;
     border-width: 0px;
     width: 500px;
 }

.aboutme{

    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 450px;

}

#header h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 4px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border:0px;
}

#profilePic{

 position: relative;
 left: 15px;
 top: -10px;
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: thin; 
 border-style: solid;
}

#skills{

}

#education{

}

#workexperience{
}

#projects{
}

#volunteering {
}

#footer {
height: 50px;
background-color:#6B8FB2;
border-width: thin;
border-color:  blue;
border-style: solid;
width: 1200px;


text-align: center;

}

#verticalLine
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 120px;
    left: 800px;
    top: 70px;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;

}
```

MY HTML code is here:

```
 <div id = "skills">
 <h3> Skills:</h3>
 <ul>
 <li>Experience in digital IC design (using ModelSim, Synplify, ispLever etc.).
 <li>Experience in C, C#, Java, SystemVerilog and Assembly programming.</li>
 <li>Experience in programming PIC, ARM and Atmel Microcontrollers.</li>
 <li>Experience in Android app development.</li>
 <li>Strong team worker and adaptable.</li>
 <li>Strong analytical and problem solving skills.</li> 
 <li>Fluency in English, Arabic and Norwegian.</li>
</li></ul>
 </div >

 <div id = "education">
 <h3> Education:</h3>
 <h4><span></span>University of Southampton (ECS)<span></span></h4>
 <h5>MEng Electronic Engineering with Nanotechnology – 2:1 (Honours)
</h5>
<ul>
<li> Fourth year group design project: Spectrum Sensing Using Imagination Technologies UCC
Communications Platform.</li> <!--Itlics-->
<li>Relevant Modules:
C and C# programming, SystemVerilog, Computer Architecture, Digital System Design, Digital Circuits & Microprocessors, 
Design & Test of Digital Systems, Electronic Design, Software Development and Computer Systems Engineering.</li>
</ul>
 <h4><span>Richmond-upon-Thames College, London</span></h4>
 <h5>BTEC National Diploma in Engineering (Triple Distinction). <p></p>AS Level Mathematics (A).</h5>

 </div>

 <div id = "workexperience">
 <h3>Work Experience:</h3>
 <h4><span>Cafe Parfait, Southampton</span></h4>
 <h5>Events Manager (August 2013 – December 2013)</h5>
 <ul>
 <li>Worked with the general manager to design and run a night out for the club.</li>
 <li>Responsible for the employment and day-to-day management of a team of
promoters (10 members).</li>
<li>Was responsible for the promotion of the club in general and the night out.</li>
 </ul>

 <h4></h4><span>SPI Lasers, Southampton</span></h4>
 <h5>Electronic Engineering Intern (July 2012 – October 2012)</h5>
 <ul>
 <li>Characterization and testing of the electronic (low cost) seed boards to ensure new lasers were up to standard.</li>
 <li>Designed a PID controller for a thermoelectric cooler (in C) that was subsequently used in the final products.</li>
 <li>Researched and documented ways of detecting the catastrophic optical damage in order to fix lasers being used in the field.</li>
 <li>Worked with supervisors, engineers and sales staff to achieve the required sales targets as well as develop a new range of low cost lasers.</li>
 </ul>

 <h4><span>Laura Ashley, London</span></h4>
 <h5>Sales Assistant (June 2011 – October 2011)</h5>
 <ul>
 <li>Served the customers and provided product information.</li>
 <li>Represented the company while selling the products provided at the flagship
store.</li>
<li>Helped with the set up of a new flagship store from the ground up.</li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div id = "projects">
 <h3>Projects:</h3>
<ul>
<li>Designed a CORDIC processor (SystemVerilog).</li>
<li>Designed a lift controller (implemented on an FPGA using SystemVerilog).</li>
<li>Designed a four-bit multiplied (implemented on a CPLD using SystemVerilog).</li>
<li>Designed a Tune generator (implemented on a PLD using SystemVerilog).</li>
<li>Developed image processing software for medical diagnosis (in C#).</li>
<li>Implemented several cognitive radio algorithms  Imagination Technologies MCP processor using assembly language.</li>
<li>Worked on the design, construction and programming (in C) of a football playing robot.</li>
<li>Designed two different sequence recognizers to be part of a digital IC.</li>
<li>Independently developed a twitter like social media Android application called Yamba.</li>
<li>Developed an Android application to control a custom-made LED cube in 48 hours (during the EMECS-thon competition).</li>
</ul>   
 </div>

 <div id = "volunteering">
 <h3>Volunteering:</h3>
 <h4><span>University of Southampton</span></h3>
 <h5>Opinions Editor for WessexScene Magazine (October 2011-June 2012)</h5>
 <ul>
 <li>Managed a team of writers and edit their work before publishing.</li>
 <li>Wrote several articles to be published on paper and online (on a range of
topics directly affecting the student population).</li>
<li>Promoted the magazine through social media and distribution.</li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div id = "footer">
 <p></p>
 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Update: Look at the second screenshot!

Final update: Look at the third screenshot![image]

[image]

Comment: not clear what expected results are. What does `get page that size` mean?

Comment: yeah I am being too vague. What I mean is that the whole page size should be from the start of the outermost red border to the end. At this point (if you look at the screen shot) there is lots of space on the right hand side. I don't want that to be there.

Comment: if window is 2000px and your container is 1200, what are you expecting? Please be very clear about expectations, if necessary create a demo

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. As I mentioned, I think that I just need to create a margin that always centers everything so that whenever the user resizes the window, the header/footer and content adjusts accordingly. At this point its not doing that.

Comment: @charlietfl, look at the screenshot with the picture. This time the header actually fills the page and when I resize the window the header resizes as well. The only issue in that case is the content is static. So does not look good when the window is resized. I guess I would have to add margins etc to make sure the content is always centered?

Comment: Yes, put a div around all of your content. Give it a width (if you want to provide different widths for different devices you could use @media tag. Then on the div around your content, set it to margin:0 auto;

Comment: or just set width as percentage for responsive sizing along with margin:auto. Might want to look into how css frameworks work also

Comment: Ah okay, will try that out now, and thanks for being patient!

Comment: Yes, the new div around all the content and adding margin:0 auto; – worked! Thanks!

Although I must say, not exactly sure what the margin:0 auto; – does though. You're setting the margin to 0, but what does the auto;- bit do?

Comment: When you set margin:0 auto;  what you are doing is setting margins top and bottom to 0 and saying that margins left and right should fill in the space on either side of the content automatically. Thereby centring your div :-)

Comment: ah makes sense, thanks!

I am guessing (just to confirm my understanding) that margin0auto;-

could also be done by doing: 

margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 0):

If you want the body to fill the available width of the page you can do it with:

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want it to look like this?
(screw it i was planning on posting a pic but i still can't due to my rep im also new, but you can just try the code yourself)

Here's the code:

```css
{
    border: red dashed 1px;
}




h3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

h4 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

h5 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}
li {
    width: 800px;
}
 #phoneNumber {
 position: relative;
        left: 950px;
        top: -110px;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-decoration:blink;
        color: black;
        width: 200px;
 }

 #emailaddress {
        position: relative;
        left: 630px;
        top: -150px;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-decoration:blink;
        color: black;
 }


#phoneIcon 
{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 617px;
    top: -60px;
}

#emailIcon
{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 670px;
    top: -130px;

}

body{
    background-color: #C4D2E0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    margin: 5px;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 99%;
}
span {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#header {

border-width: thin;
border-color:  blue;
border-style: solid;

background-color:#6B8FB2;
position: relative;
height: 250px;
text-align: center;
font-family: monospace;
font-style: oblique;
text-align: justify;
width: 1200px;

}

 #aboutmeDiv
 {
     position: relative;
     max-width: 1100px;
     left: 210px;
     top: -250px;
     margin-right: 800px;
     border-style: dashed green 1px;
     border-width: 0px;
     width: 500px;
 }

.aboutme{

    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 450px;

}

#header h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 4px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border:0px;
}

#profilePic{

 position: relative;
 left: 15px;
 top: -10px;
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: thin; 
 border-style: solid;
}

#skills{

}

#education{

}

#workexperience{
}

#projects{
}

#volunteering {
}

#footer {
height: 50px;
background-color:#6B8FB2;
border-width: thin;
border-color:  blue;
border-style: solid;
width:99%;


text-align: center;

}

#verticalLine
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 120px;
    left: 800px;
    top: 70px;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;

}
```

I only changed a few width values to 99% instead of fixed pixels. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! but nah, not really, all it did was make the header's width smaller. I think that the problem is actually the margins. I need to use them to keep everything centered as the user re-sizes the window. Like if you move your current window now (as you are reading this comment), you will see how the content moves as well. The content sorta stretches with the size of the window!

Comment: ahhh you wanted to center them, i didn't know i thought you wanted to get rid of that empty space :) if that is so... hmm you can group everything div maybe? and move them as one. :) or center align the div.

Comment: Yea, @Leo Farmer, answered it :)!